# Are the confidence intervals of logit model coefficients normally distributed?

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-error, logit, composite

In more detail to the above...

I have a GLM with a logit link examining behaviours (success = 1, failure = 0) across some quite large datasets (n ~ 30,000 to 3,000,000). The IVs are standardised and centred.

I want to calculate a composite metric that represents the **relative** or normalised scale of each coefficient by dividing the absolute value of each coefficient by the sum of all coefficients (again, absolute values). I would also like to add confidence intervals to this metric. Ideally, I would like to do this directly from the data I already have on the coefficients (e.g. using only SEs or CIs). However, I am approaching this with some caution as it is somewhat beyond my statistics competency. I am particularly stuck on the nature of the confidence intervals and the assumed distribution of possible coeffient values between the upper and lower CIs.

If I assume the confidence intervals are associated with a normally distributed range of coefficient values, then I can calculate CIs of the composite metric using monte-carlo analysis or similar. However, the non-linearity of logit models makes me suspect they are not normally distributed. Although I am not sure. Hence the questions:

1. Are the CIs of logit model coefficients associated with a probability distribution? (normal?)

If not...

2. How do I (or can I) calculate CIs for a composite coefficient metric using just the SEs or CIs from the individual coefficients?

Comment: I am fairly sure coefficients have a normal distribution (under the model assumptions). 
Is there a reason you are normalizing by the sum of coefficients, rather than in some more ordinary way (e.g. by standardizing the IVs to have a sd of 1)?
Have you considered bootstrapping?

Comment: @dash2 - thanks - any refs or examples though? IVs already centred and standardised. I believe sample variation in logit models affects the scale of coefficients so am exploring whether rescaling might allow for a tentative comparison between popoulations in a manner not too dissimilar from ranking cofficients (cross-population comparisons are generally a no go in logit models). Haven't undertaken bootstrapping before but reluctantly considering it. Monte Carlo is preferred because of sample size and I know how to do it/can use a simple Excel model and defined distribution (tools: Excel/SPSS).

Comment: Why not compare the marginal effects in terms of probability (at appropriate fixed values)? (Sorry.. I don't know the right refs... and thinking about it, maybe the coefficients have a normal distribution only as N gets large...)

Comment: @dash2 no problem, always worth checking! I thought about marginal effects, but the results would only be valid for the 'fixed values' at which I calculate them (also, MEs at the mean might describe a situation that does not exist). I think the relative scale of the marginal probabilities is constant whatever the fixed values selected and therefore mathematically equivalent to the relative scale of the coefficients described above, but not sure. I have a large n (30k - 4m) so computing marginal effects and their relative scale across 20 coefs using bootstrapping is v computationally intensive.

Comment: You are also going to need the covariances, and not just the standard errors, of the coefficients. So this is impossible as written. Then you would need to use the delta method of the ratio. People rarely do this by hand since it's a pain.