# Bootstrapping confidence intervals for a non-linear combination of logit coefficients using R

Tags: r, confidence-interval, bootstrap, composite

I have a GLM with a logit link examining behaviours (success = 1, failure = 0) across several large datasets (n > 30,000). The IVs are standardised and centred.

I would like to produce a metric of 'relative importance' for each coefficient,
essentially a normalised scale, calculated as the absolute Beta value of each coefficient divided by the sum of the (absolute) Beta values of all coefficients - e.g. Abs[A] / (Abs[A] + Abs[B] + ...). I am using this as a tentative method to compare the importance of coefficients between groups. Having asked another question around the theory behind this ([Are the confidence intervals of logit model coefficients normally distributed?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/348340/are-the-confidence-intervals-of-logit-model-coefficients-normally-distributed)), it appears that I may need to 'brute force' the answer through bootstrapping in R or equivalent. I am trying to find out where and how I can do this within the bootstrap process. I am new to R, and am currently here with my code:

```
library(multcomp)
library(rms)
library(boot)

mydata = read.csv("Raw_Data.csv")

GLM_boot <- function(data,indices){
d <-data[indices,]
GLM_model <- glm(formula = cbind(Successes, Failures) ~ A + B + C + D, family = binomial, data=d)
coef (GLM_model)}

boot_results = boot(data = mydata, statistic = GLM_boot, R = 1000)

boot_results
```

As I understand it, I need to include an evaluation for A / (A + B + C + D) and its associated 95% confidence interval or standard error, and so on for B / (A +...) etc. within the GLM_boot function and then pass this information out as a vector. I have taken some time to look at other questions on StatsExchange before posting, but have not found anything close enough, although happy to be redirected if I am mistaken.

Code derived from examples within:
http://www.bio.ic.ac.uk/research/mjcraw/therbook/index.htm
and
http://people.tamu.edu/~alawing/materials/ESSM689/Btutorial.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to include that evaluation inside the GLM_boot function, you can do it with a post-bootstrap processing step.  This post-processing step modifies the returned bootstrap parameter values according to your desired transform.

I've constructed an example with a simple linear model but the same transform you wish to use:

```
# Construct data frame
df <- data.frame(A=rnorm(100), B=rnorm(100), C=rnorm(100), D=rnorm(100))
df$y <- df$A + 2*df$B + 3*df$C + 4*df$D + 5*rnorm(100)

GLM_boot <- function(data,indices){
   d <-data[indices,]
   GLM_model <- glm(y ~ A + B + C + D, data=d)
   coef (GLM_model)}

boot_results = boot(data = df, statistic = GLM_boot, R = 1000)

# Now we'll restate the coefficients as desired inside the boot object
postprocess <- function(br) {
   br$t0 <- br$t0 / sum(br$t0)
   br$t <- br$t / rowSums(br$t)
   br
}
```

... and the output...

```
> postprocess(boot_results)

ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
boot(data = df, statistic = GLM_boot, R = 1000)


Bootstrap Statistics :
      original        bias    std. error
t1* 0.03483616  0.0008814079  0.04744519
t2* 0.10487991 -0.0032297441  0.05578734
t3* 0.16269011  0.0023995123  0.04332950
t4* 0.29902332  0.0009167799  0.04952932
t5* 0.39857050 -0.0009679560  0.04891230
>
```

We are not restricted to maintain the dimensionality of the parameters inside the boot object; below I modify the object so that both the original and the ratio versions of the parameters are reported.

```
pp2 <- function(br) {
   br$t0 <- c(br$t0, br$t0/sum(br$t0))
   br$t <- cbind(br$t, br$t/rowSums(br$t))
   br
}

> pp2(boot_results)

ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
boot(data = df, statistic = GLM_boot, R = 1000)


Bootstrap Statistics :
       original        bias    std. error
t1*  0.35231765  0.0327456957  0.48938051
t2*  1.06070932  0.0049052064  0.60399757
t3*  1.64537622  0.0453722673  0.51060026
t4*  3.02419044  0.0004190907  0.44728859
t5*  4.03096685 -0.0112095514  0.48327601
t6*  0.03483616  0.0008814079  0.04744519
t7*  0.10487991 -0.0032297441  0.05578734
t8*  0.16269011  0.0023995123  0.04332950
t9*  0.29902332  0.0009167799  0.04952932
t10* 0.39857050 -0.0009679560  0.04891230
>
```